# Limit access to pdf page with php

Tags: php, pdf

With PHP, I am developing a script that generates a contract once the script is validated.

The contract is a pdf document generated with TCPDF and I save it to the server in a subdirectory with the user's ID. For example, 'contracts/132/1.pdf' would be bill #1 of user with ID 132.

However, I want only user 132 to be able to access that file, because it contains personal information. How can I limit the access to pdf documents in each subfolder to their respective user (using php or htaccess, whichever works best - I'm not very familiar with htaccess)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to have a PHP script that requires the existence of a valid session (like the generator script does), whose function is to `readfile("/path/to/contract.pdf");`

That way, you can have your PDF wrapper script verify that the contract being downloaded is the RIGHT contract for the person in the sesion, not just that it's a contract that is in the directory.

The problem with a .htaccess-based solution on the directory is that anyone with read access to the directory can download ANY contract.

Given a URL like `http://example.com/contract.php?user=132&bill=1` you could:

```
<?php

$user = $_GET['user'];
$bill = $_GET['bill'];
# do input validation on $user and $bill.  No really, do it.

if ($user != $_SESSION['user']) {
  die("Security error; the black choppers are on their way.");
}

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Contract-$user-$bill.pdf"');

readfile("/path/to/pdfspool/$user/Contract-$user-$bill.pdf");
```

The `if ()` chunk in the middle verifies that the $user being requested is valid for the current user.  Obviously, you'll want to store $_SESSION['user'], probably when this user first logs in.

Of course, you don't NEED to keep spool files, really.  If the process of generating a PDF isn't going to overwhelm your web server (and if it does you have other problems), it may just be easier to re-generate each PDF from scratch, on request.  That's what I do with company invoices now, and each invoice gets a 6 point footer saying when it was generated and by a request from what IP address.  :)

Comment: What if the user is wise enough to type in the direct URL to the PDF script in the address bar? For example, typing www.mysite.com/contracts/124/5.pdf.

Comment: Updated.  I've added a section to the code that validates $user against a session variable.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you'd place the PDF files outside of the site's web root and retrieve them via a script.

This can be made seamless by combining a Mod_Rewrite rule that passes requests to where the PDFs would be retrieved from to a PHP script that gets user and document IDs from the URL and performs access control, which if it succeeds, outputs the file's contents.

See [the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) for details on how to perform HTTP-level authentication using PHP code.

Comment: What do you mean by "place the PDF files outside of the site's web root"? Can you illustrate it by an example?

Comment: If your web root is located at `/home/user/public_html`, place the files in `/home/user/pdfs`. As long as PHP can read from the contents of the `/home/user/pdfs` directory, it will be able to retrieve the files' contents, but they will not be directly accessible from the web.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that - wise idea.